# Vector calculus problem involving planes

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I'm working on a vector calculus problem (provided below) and the issue is I'm getting two different answers, and I'm not sure which is right.

> The question is as follows:
>   Calculate the surface integral $\int_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} $ over a triangular surface bound by the points $(2,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,2)$, where $\vec{F} = (x, y, z)$ and $d\vec{S} = \vec{n} dS$, with $\vec{n} $ being the outward unit normal. 
>   (Hint: the plane equation is $ax+by+cz=1$, use it to find the normal, using the points on the surface)

I started with the plane points, and found that:
$$\frac{1}{2} (x+y+z)=1$$
Yielding a normal of $\frac{1}{2} (1,1,1)$. 
Using the surface integral:
$$\int_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{S} (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{N} )dxdy$$

Which I computed to be
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{S} (x+y+z) dxdy = \frac{1}{2} \int_{S} 2 dxdy = 2$$ 
Using the area of the projected triangle on the $xy$ plane.

What I don't understand is, if I rewrite the plane as
$$x+y+z=2$$
And compute the integral, I get an answer of $4$? 
Given the same plane equations (just rearranged), I don't understand where I'm losing  the factor of two, or as to which answer is actually correct?

All help appreciated!

Comment: For vectors you should have a space between `\vec` and the argument, e.g. `\vec F`.

Comment: Fixed, thank you very much :)

Comment: The unit normal should be $\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)$, not $\frac12(1,1,1)$ (which has length $\sqrt{3}/2$) or $(1,1,1)$ (which has length $\sqrt3$).

Comment: But when parameterising the magnitude gets absorbed because $\vec{n} dS = \vec{n} Ndxdy = \vec{N} dxdy$ so that shouldn't matter?